# define a specific mail-relay for a specif group in Exchange

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010, gateway

So, my question is, how do I define a specific mail-relay for a specif group in Exchange.

Lets say I have an exchange server (2010) in IP 10.0.0.1, the default mail gate-way is 10.0.0.2, now, I have a specific group of people which I want to route they're mails throw 10.0.0.3 because it has a different service on it.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Exchange doesn't allow you to select smart hosts / smtp relay server based on the sender. You'd need to use a 3rd party tool for that. Try [MultiSendcon](http://www.servolutions.com/multisendcon.htm) - that's easy to install and allows you to specify the mail gateway based on the sender addresses.